# Android Studio - How is this GUI-Item called?

Tags: android

I´m just searching for an GUI-Element, which I can only descripe.
After long time searching for the name or any tip, I do not have any more ideas.
So just thanks for your help!

Im searching for a GUI-Element (similar to DatePicker), something with the design of a RecyclerView, only horizontal and the functonality of a Spinner.
So for example I have 5 categories to choose in my app and **ONE of them HAS TO BE SELECTED PERMANENTLY**.
The user can change the selected cetegories by swiping left or right. The selected item is in the middle and highlighted in any way.
Under the GUI-Element, I´m searching for there can be a list with results for the selected categorie or something.

**Like this:**

Departures | **Arrivals**   |    Destinations

*-> after a swipe to the left*

Arrivals     | **Destinations**  | Airlines

*-> after a swipe to the left again*

Destinations  | **Airlines**

I hope you can image what Im searching for.
Thanks for every help or inspiration how to solve this issue.
Have a great day!

Comment: Sounds like a [Scrollable Tab](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tabs#scrollable-tabs) May help to review: https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#lateral-navigation

Comment: Yes, that´s exactly what I´m searching for! Thank you so much @MorrisonChang

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for a horizontal RecyclerView.
Maybe take a look at [Recycler View Horizontal Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328732/recycler-view-horizontal-android)